# Can we use spool function in toad

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, toad

I am able to use spool using sql*plus
We can use the UTL function for that.

But what I want to know, whether we use a spool in toad for Oracle.

I have tried and received the error `Ora-00900`.

Comment: Please post a full code that you execute and the full error you're getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spool` is a SQL*Plus internal command so you cannot use it as plsql command

but you can easily do this through toad itself by

1- Write and Run the query into toad.

2- Right click on your datagrid in toad.

3- click on `Export Dataset` option and choose the configuration you want.